# Heap fragmentation due to extensive new/delete operation on ARM M4

Tags: gcc, arm, heap-memory

**Toolchain**: e.g. the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10-2020-q4-major for compiling a program for a lightwight embedded ARM Cortex M4 target.

**Src**: A source code which continuously uses new/delete to allocate memory for a variable sized array.

**The question**: Must I care about heap memory fragmentation or are there any measure build in to prevent this.

Comment: `Theoretical question.` `Must I care` No. `are there any measure build` Don't use `new`.

Comment: While it is not recommended to use `new`, if you are in C++, sometimes there is no other option, especially if you have things like *GUI* where widgets are dynamically loaded, etc. but try to avoid `new` anyway, or provide custom heap management.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will avoid it.